# Powershell script - error control and ensuring the order of items in an array workflow

Tags: powershell

I have a script below, the purpose of the script is as follows.

1. Pass a file to the script containing a list of SQL instances.
2. Pass an array of files to the script.
3. Run each and every script on all the SQL instances defined in the file from step 1

```
param(
    [string[]] $file_list,
    [string] $in_sql_server_instances_file_path
)

if (!(test-path $in_sql_server_instances_file_path)) {
    write-output "The file does not exist"
    return 1
}

$file_server_list = get-content -path $in_sql_server_instances_file_path

workflow execute-parallel {
    param(
        [string []]
        $sql_instances,
        [string []]
        $files_to_execute
    )

    foreach -parallel -throttlelimit 8 ($sql_instance in $sql_instances) {

        inlineScript {
            $wf_sql_instance = $using:sql_instance
            $wf_files_to_execute = $using:files_to_execute

            foreach ($file_to_execute in $wf_files_to_execute) {
                Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "$wf_sql_instance" -Database "tempdb" -InputFile $file_to_execute
            }
        }
    }
}

execute-parallel -sql_instances $file_server_list -files_to_execute $file_list
```

To execute the script.

```
.\execute.ps1 -file_list 'C:\Scripts\a.sql','C:\Scripts\b.sql' -in_sql_server_instances_file_path 'C:\Scripts\sql_file.txt'
```

sql_file.txt contains a list of SQL instances.

I am trying to achieve the following.

1. If a file fails, stop execution on the server but move onto the next server in the loop.
2. Handle error control
3. Deploy the files in the order specified in the `-file_list` array parameter.
4. How can I be certain that `a.sql` will always run before `b.sql`?

Comment: Is this a hypothetical question or have you actually run into problems? Your current approach (using array parameters) already guarantees the file list order - arrays don't magically re-order themselves :)

Comment: @ Mathias I just wanted to be sure with regards to the ordering in case there was some kind of behaviour to be aware of, secondly not sure how the error control will be handled based on the requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerShell standard hash tables are weird when it comes to order. But not arrays.